# Sony Experia won't let me enter my voicemail PIN

Tags: keyboard, voicemail

I call my voice mail and it asks me for my PIN. After entering 3 out of the 4 digits, the screen starts blinking not allowing me to enter the fourth, then telling me I entered an incorrect PIN.

So the phone makes it impossible for me to retrieve my voicemail.

Comment: I assume you mean PIN (numbers only) not password (alpha-numeric). Are you sure you have to enter the PIN via keyboard/dialing tones? Usually nowadays you can also speak to such systems just saying the PIN numbers.

Comment: You are correct, vm pin